# Not getting any callback after calling muteRemoteAudioStream(uid, toMute) this method

Tags: android, voice, agora.io

We need to implement functionality that Admin should be able to mute anyone in channel, for this we have used your function

> **muteRemoteAudioStream(uid, toMute)**

We also want to show everyone that this user has been muted... But for now we are not getting any callback in method

> **onRemoteAudioStateChanged(uid, state, reason, elapsed)**

I' m using agora voice sdk version : **3.3.0 (implementation 'io.agora.rtc:voice-sdk:3.3.0')**

Kindly help us on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please define and create the IRtcEngineEventHandler when initializing the RtcEngine instance. This will make sure that onRemoteAudioStateChanged be called when the remote audio state change (e.g. remote user mute).

Agora currently does not provide similar API for remotely mute any users. But you can achieve this by using Agora RTM (Real Time Messaging) SDK. You can send a signal from the "Admin" user to the remote users. When the remote users receive the message, they can call muteLocalAudioStream method to mute themselves.

Here is the guide for RTM SDK: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android